# Update drop down list dynamically - xpages

Tags: xpages

I have a form with two drop down type ahead fields.  The first one works but the second one has to use different views based upon the input of the first value (actually a viewScope variable stored after the first is input).  The second drop down is empty no matter what is typed into the first one.  I will include the code I have for the selectItems for the second field below.  I also will include the visible code to only display the second field for certain circumstances.  Can you please take a look at what I have?  Thanks for your help.  (the views in the code are all data sources)

```
switch(viewScope.vsTieIn) {
    case "0046":
        return viewAceLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewAceLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewAceLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewAceLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0009":
       return viewDIBLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewDIBLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewDIBLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewDIBLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0166":
        return viewOrgillLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewOrgillLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewOrgillLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewOrgillLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0016":
        return viewPPGLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewPPGLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewPPGLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewPPGLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0005":
        return viewTrueValueLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewTrueValueLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewTrueValueLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewTrueValueLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0026":
        return viewAllProLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewAllProLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewAllProLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewAllProLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
}
```

VISIBLE CODE:

```
getComponent("DropShip").getValue() || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0046" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0009" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0166" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0016" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0005" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0026";
```

Here is the xsp code:

```
<xe:djFilteringSelect
                                                        id="djFilteringSelect1"
                                                        value="#{document1.CustInput}"
                                                        ignoreCase="true"
                                                        promptMessage="Enter a Customer ID, Phone or Name"
                                                        invalidMessage="Invalid Entry - check spelling"
                                                        style="width:150px"
                                                        autoComplete="true">
                                                        <xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("DropShip").getValue() || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0046" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0009" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0166" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0016" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0005" || 
viewScope.vsTieIn == "0026";}]]></xe:this.rendered>
                                                        <xp:selectItem
                                                            itemLabel=""
                                                            id="selectItem2">
                                                        </xp:selectItem>
                                                        <xp:selectItems id="selectItems1">
                                                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:switch(viewScope.vsTieIn) {
    case "0046":
        return viewAceLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewAceLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewAceLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewAceLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0009":
       return viewDIBLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewDIBLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewDIBLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewDIBLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0166":
        return viewOrgillLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewOrgillLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewOrgillLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewOrgillLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0016":
        return viewPPGLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewPPGLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewPPGLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewPPGLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0005":
        return viewTrueValueLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewTrueValueLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewTrueValueLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewTrueValueLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
    case "0026":
        return viewAllProLkup.getColumnValues(0) + viewAllProLkup.getColumnValues(1) + viewAllProLkup.getColumnValues(2) + "|" + viewAllProLkup.getColumnValues(0);
        break;
} 
}]]></xp:this.value>
                                                        </xp:selectItems>
                                                        <xp:eventHandler
                                                            event="onChange"
                                                            submit="true"
                                                            refreshMode="partial"
                                                            id="eventHandler10" refreshId="custTable">
                                                            <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var compID = getComponent("djFilteringSelect1").getValue();

var custDoc:NotesDocument = viewCustByID.getDocumentByKey(compID);

//Set Billing Info
document1.setValue("BillCompID", custDoc.getItemValue("CustID"));
viewScope.vsBillCompID = custDoc.getItemValue("CustID");
viewScope.vsBillFax = custDoc.getItemValue("CustFax");

//Set Shipping Info 
document1.setValue("ShipCompName", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipName"));
document1.setValue("ShipAddr1", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipAddr1"));
document1.setValue("ShipAddr2", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipAddr2"));
document1.setValue("ShipAddr3", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipAddr3"));
document1.setValue("ShipCity", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipCity"));
document1.setValue("ShipState", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipState"));
document1.setValue("ShipZip", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipZip"));
document1.setValue("ShipProv", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipProv"));
document1.setValue("ShipCountry", custDoc.getItemValue("CustShipCntry"));

var a = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillName");
var b = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillAddr1");
var c = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillAddr2");
var d = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillAddr3");
var e = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillCity");
var f = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillState");
var g = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillZip");
var h = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillProv");
var i = custDoc.getItemValue("CustBillCntry");
var j = custDoc.getItemValue("CustPhone");

viewScope.a = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillName");
viewScope.b = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillAddr1");
viewScope.c = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillAddr2");
viewScope.d = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillAddr3");
viewScope.e = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillCity");
viewScope.f = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillState");
viewScope.g = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillZip");
viewScope.h = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillProv");
viewScope.i = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustBillCntry");
viewScope.j = custDoc.getItemValueString("CustPhone");
document1.setValue("BillCompInfo", a + "<br />" + b + (c ? "<br />" + c : "") + (d ? "<br />" + d : "") + "<br />" + e + ", " + f + g + (h ? "<br />" + h + " " : "") + (i ? ", " + i : "") + (j ? "<br />" + j : ""));

document1.setValue("OrderStatus", "Draft");
viewScope.vsTerms = custDoc.getItemValue("CustTerms");
viewScope.vsDiscCode = custDoc.getItemValue("CustDiscCode");
viewScope.vsTradeDisc = custDoc.getItemValue("CustTradeDisc");
viewScope.vsTieIn = custDoc.getItemValue("CustTieIn");
viewScope.vsPromoCode = custDoc.getItemValue("CustPromoGroup");
viewScope.vsPromoBypass = custDoc.getItemValue("CustPromoBypass");
document1.setValue("djFilteringSelect1", "");
getComponent("djFilteringSelect1").setValue("");

if(document1.isNewNote()) {
    var vUNID = session.evaluate("@Unique").elementAt(0);
    document1.setValue("OrderUNID", vUNID);
    viewScope.vsOrderUNID = vUNID;
}
}]]></xe:this.action>
                                                        </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

Comment: Would be easier to get it if you'd posted the whole source of your page / the relevant XSP source (not just the SSJS part).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here http://tc-soft.com/blog/377

Your second combo has to be refreshed by the first one. So first combo must fire partial refresh to the area of second combo.

Comment: I'm doing a full refresh after the first one on the onchange event.  The first one sets the viewScope variable.  I can set any of the cases in the default and it will execute the default list but I get that every time, not selected by the viewScope variable.